# Lim to 0, sinx/x theory

Tags: limits

I have noticed that when $\lim_{x \to 0}$, i can divide $sinx, tan x$ with $ x$
$\lim_{\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} $ become $\lim_{\to 0} 1$ but cannot with $\cos x$?

Also, Is it applied when to 0 only? 
Because sin $0 = 0$, and $x = 0$. 
Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the formal definition of limit and understood its intuitive meaning? It might give you a good hindsight for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the case of $\cos(x)$, notice that $\cos(0)=1$. So, obviously, near $x=0$, $\displaystyle \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ does not converge.

Whereas, in the case of a $0/0$ limit, there is still a chance of convergence, and we can determine whether by futher analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is differentiable and $a$ is a point of its domain, then the limit$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}$$exists (in $\mathbb R$) if and only if $f(a)=0$. In fact:

- If $f(a)=0$, then that limit is $f'(a)$.
- If $f(a)\neq0$, then$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}+\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(a)}{x-a};$$the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists (it is equal to $f'(a)$), but the other one doesn't.

In particular, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=\sin'(0)=1$, but the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}x$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb R$.